# Angularjs doesn't change datepicker date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I tried many solutions  from this site marked as anwers still the datepicker doesn't change the date format. i'm using this angular directive with no results:

```
App.directive('datepicker', function() {
       return function(scope, element, attrs) {
           element.datepicker({
               inline: true,
               dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
               onSelect: function(dateText) {
                   var modelPath = $(this).attr('ng-model');
                   putObject(modelPath, scope, dateText);
                   scope.$apply();
               }
           });
       }
    });
```

also on the html:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="finalDate" date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" date-type="string" datepicker>
```

nothing either, added this code in the script:

```
  $scope.$watch('datepicker.date', function(v){ // using the example model from the datepicker docs
        var d = new Date(v);
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        $scope.modDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
        console.log($scope.modDate)
    })
```

the console log prints nothing. Honestly i don't know what else to do, i tried other solutions with no result. any ideas?

**EDIT:** Plunker added http://plnkr.co/edit/hoGYFslN3KovH0wkj5kE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use this **directive**

```
App.directive('datepicker', ['$filter', '$parse', function ($filter, $parse) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        element.datetimepicker({
            weekStart: 1,
            todayBtn: 1,
            autoclose: 1,
            todayHighlight: 1,
            startView: 2,
            minView: 2,
            forceParse: 0,
            endDate: attrs.enddate == "" ? new Date() : null,
            format: "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            var dateUTC = new Date(ev.date.getTime() + (ev.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
            var filterApply = $filter('date')(dateUTC, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, filterApply);
            scope.$digest();
        });
    }
}}]);
```

if you want to use your directive, it should be like

```
App.directive('datepicker', function ($filter, $parse) {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.datepicker({
        inline: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            var dateUTC = new Date(dateText.date.getTime() + (dateText.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
            var filterApply = $filter('date')(dateUTC, 'dd/mm/yy');
            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, filterApply);
            scope.$digest();
        }
    });
}});
```

Comment: None of them are works, if its any help im using angularjs v. 1.3.14 and datepicker v. 1.4

Comment: can you please make a plunker, so i can fix it over there?

Comment: Its working dude, see your plunker :) its formatting , what else you want to do

Comment: yes and no, it's formating but the format you see it's **MM/dd/yyyy** and not **dd/MM/yyyy**

Comment: change format MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy, i didn't get your point. what wrong in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90070/discussion-between-kashif-mustafa-and-b-j-a-a).